# Centering p elements not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center p elements, but nothing I try is working. It worked on a previous version of the page, but I can't understand why it isn't currently working.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="aligncenter">

<p class='alignleft'>
    <img src="images/about1.jpg" alt="cupcakes" style="width:300px;height=224px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <p class='alignright'>
    <img src="images/about4.jpg" alt="cupcakes2" style="width:300px;height=224px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
     width:300px;
     color: #604209;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;


}
.alignright {
    float: right;
     width:300px;
     color: #604209;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;

}

.aligncenter {
  style=width:800px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: #604209;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.alignright {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  color: #604209;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.aligncenter {
  style=width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligncenter">

  <p class='alignleft'>
    <img src="images/about1.jpg" alt="cupcakes" style="width:300px;height=224px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p class='alignright'>
    <img src="images/about4.jpg" alt="cupcakes2" style="width:300px;height=224px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can center these p elements?

Comment: If you want to centre them, remove the floats. But I suspect you don't mean that and you want to centre the contents... Right?

Comment: use `.aligncenter { display: block; }` instead of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: How do you want to center p elements when you applied alignleft and alignright classes to them??

Comment: Do you really have `style=width:800px;` in your CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your CSS.

In your `aligncenter` class you have declared `width` as 800px and then again overwritten it with 50%; What you need is `min-width` property. Setting min-width will keep the min-width to at least 600px will do, because it enough to hold the left and right aligned contents which sums up a total of 600px. Setting width 50% will be less than 600px if the overall width is less than 1200px.

Also using `display: inline-block` not letting you center your contents. Because this property is used to fill the browsers whole width, which clearly you don't want here.

And is `style=width: 800px` really in your CSS or just a typo?

Update your `aligncenter` class as below and everything should work as expected.

```css
.alignleft {
    float: left;
     width:300px;
     color: #604209;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;


}
.alignright {
    float: right;
     width:300px;
     color: #604209;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;

}

.aligncenter {
  width:50%; 
  min-width: 600px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligncenter">

<p class='alignleft'>
    <img src="images/about1.jpg" alt="cupcakes">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <p class='alignright'>
    <img src="images/about4.jpg" alt="cupcakes2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The style=bit in the CSS was a typo, yes. This code works, it does exactly what I wanted to do, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put **text-align: center;** in class **.aligncenter**. And put **display: block** instead of inline-block.

```
.aligncenter {
  width:800px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/margwt9h/6/).

Answer (score 0):

For me it works if you remove the `display: inline-block;` from `.aligncenter`. `inline-block` will always reserve the full available width (at least if no other inline-block elements appear as "neighbours", see [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)).

Please also note, that using the `'` (single quotation mark) like in `<p class='alignleft'>` is no valid html style (though most browsers accept it). You should always use double quotation marks: `<p class="alignleft">`.

Hope this helps!